# Returning a result from function using jquery and typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript

Here is my code pen link:https://codepen.io/saisree/pen/yXeaqy

```
interface Named {
    getSalutation:() => string;
}

class Person {
    constructor(
    private name:string, 
    private age:number
  ) {}

    getSalutation():string {
        return `${this.name}, age ${this.age}`;
    }
}
```

Here I'm not understanding how the return function is working?
can someone please explain y the result is kept in between backtick(``)
Is it something related to angular or jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). They were introduced as part of ES6 and not a jQuery or Angular feature. They can be used to embed expressions inside strings.

For example:

```
`One plus two is: ${1 + 2}` // Prints "One plus two is: 3"
```

MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals